# Increase input value by Math Random function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some inputs, and when it focused, value increases by 10 times, I can see this value in console, but I cant push into certain input value. Any ideas?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1); 
    $('body').append("<input type='text' value='" + random + "'>") 
    $('input').focus(function() { 
        console.log(+$(this).val() * 10) 
    }) 
}
```

Comment: `$('#certainInput').val(+$(this).val() * 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `focus` event outside the loop and set the value of the input with `.val()`

```
// Get
$('#inputId').val()

// Set
$('#inputId').val( 10 )
```

[.val() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1); 
    $('body').append("<input type='text' value='" + random + "'>") 
}
$('input').focus(function() { 
  $(this).val( parseInt($(this).val()) * 10 );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```